# Window powershell to launch jupyter notebook (By using a different enviroment other than base)

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook

Whenever i tried to launch jupyter notebook from a **specific location (Folder)** using windows powershell. It launches using base environment but i don't want to use base environment. Can anyone help me in this regards.

**Command i use in powershell:**

```
jupyter notebook
```

I tried to activate enviroment from windows powershell but it didn't work.
But when i use `conda env list` it shows the installed environments in the machine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say "I tried to activate environment from windows powershell but it didn't work" what exactly do you mean? What did you try? and what was the error message?

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe No error message appears on screen. 

conda activate tensoflow_env

Comment: do you have jupyter installed in `tensorflow_env`?

Comment: Have activate the virtual environment?